# Distinct metrics for Cubism (Square/Cube)

Tags: c#, mongodb, rest, cubism.js, square-cube

I'm looking for a rest call to square/cube that will give me a distinct list of a certain property from my events. My property is a string on the `data` property of the cube event.

Is that possible to do via REST?

Answer (score 0):

Cube objects are stored as objects / dictionaries in MongoDB, so it's definitely possible to access their `data` property. The required data is in a database called `cube_development`.

Play around with it a bit to get a feel for the data, and then use the MongoDB [C# driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/) to access the data.

Hope this helps!